# Recursion - making array list with 100 integers

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, arraylist

I have finished the first part of a homework assignment and I'm starting to get stuck (partially confused on the instructions. I currently have some completed code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ListMethods
{
 public static ArrayList<Integer> makeList(int n)

 {

 ArrayList<Integer> tempList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

 if (n <= 0) // The smallest list we can make

 {
     return tempList;
 }
 else // All other size lists are created here

 {

 }
 return tempList;

 }
}



public class ListMethodRunner
 {
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
         ArrayList<Integer> tempList = ListMethods.makeList(0);
         if(tempList.size() == 0)
         {
         System.out.println("The list is empty.");
         }
         else
         {
             for(Integer i: tempList)
             {
                 System.out.println(i);
             }
         }
     }
}
```

The goal right now is to use these instructions: *Whenever a method calls itself, the method is recursive. By calling the same
method again, each instance of a problem is solved using the solution to a smaller instance. Logically, this
process has to stop somewhere. In the case of our ArrayList problem, it stops when we call
makeList(0). This is the problem we solved by hand in Lab 1.1.
Whenever we call makeList(n - 1) we receive an ArrayList with 1, 2, 3, …, n - 1. How can we use
that to produce an ArrayList with 1, 2, 3, …, n?
Add that code to the else block and complete the makeList method. Test your code with the test harness
by changing the argument that is passed to makeList. Can you make a list with 100 items?*

I need to make a list with 100 items but I don't understand how to do this with 100 items using the (n-1). If I understand this correctly, seeing as how we can't use while loops, I would use something like (int i = 0, i<100, i++) right?

Comment: The question specifically refers to using recursion, so I would think any kind of loop would be disallowed.

Answer (score 1):

`makeList(n)` makes a list of `n` elements.  If you could make a list of `n-1` elements, you could just add the `n` to it.  Fortunately, you *have* a method that can do just that: `makeList` when called with `n-1`.

Comment: Props for making them think :D

Comment: I think I'm still confused on how to define makeList(n-1) where it will make a list with 100 elements

Comment: That's the beauty of recursion: it's just a normal call to `makeList`: you don't need to define anything new.  (Don't worry about keeping track of the different calls to `makeList`; that kind of bookkeeping is what computers excel at!)

Answer (score 0):

Recursion involves the method will be calling itself, so your first hint is that within `makeList` you'll have to be calling `makeList`. 

ecursion is usually an alternative to loops, you're most likely expected to solve this not only avoiding "while" loops, but any kind of loop.